# merging legends when creating a facet chart in Altair

Tags: facet, altair, vega-lite

I am trying to create a facet grid of plots in Altair. I have two different data frames that have a common x axis, and a common category for the facet, but each with a different column for determining the color. To plot, I merge these into a single data frame. The problem I am having is that the legend is being displayed on each plot individually. I want the legend just to appear once, at the side of the facet. Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do and the current results.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
                    'y1':[6,7,8,1,3,5,9,8,7],
                    'cat':['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],
                    'E1':[120,120,120,200,200,200,80,80,80]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5],
                    'y2':[6,8,8,9,2,4,6,8,9,7,5,4,3],
                    'cat':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C'],
                    'E2':[2,1,3,2,1,1,3,2,3,2,2,2,3]})

merged = pd.merge(df2,df1, how='outer', on=['cat','x'])

p1 = alt.Chart(merged).mark_line().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y1:Q',
    color=alt.Color('E1:Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='viridis'), bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=5))
)

p2 = alt.Chart(merged).mark_circle().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y2:Q',
    color=alt.Color('E2:N', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[1,2,3],range=['black','red','blue']))
)

alt.layer(p1 + p2).facet('cat:N')
```

[image: altair facet legend problem example]

Comment: This might be a bug in vega-lite with layered charts, you could raise it on their issue tracker. `alt.layer(p1).facet('cat:N')` works just fine